# GDIPlus Gradient along a circular GraphicsPath

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, graphicspath

I have a "donut" in a graphics path.

I would like to draw a gradient along that path and control when a color starts and ends by a given start and end angle on the circle.

Like this:

http://www.andresilvadesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Gauge-icon-design.jpg

A LinearGradient can only go one angle, and does not follow the path properly.

The PathGradientBrush seems to be just.. a circular gradient?
I cant seem to find a way to do this properly in C#.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Could you draw a full circle using the PathGradientBrush, then mask it, say with a gauge face like in the image, or with a circle (and/or pie wedge) in the background color?

Comment: i guess i could, but how would drawing a full circle help? im trying to get the gradient to go along the edge of it, not from inside to outside ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, and the author probably doesn't much care anymore, but I have searched the web for an answer to this question and I could not find any.

KeithS' link in the comment [bobpowell.net/pgb.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20140906083853/http://bobpowell.net/pgb.aspx) was not working for me because I could not find a way to get the real number of points used to draw the curve. (See the paragraph "Got them surrounded.")

To attempt to emulate the color wheel I thus wrote this code: (I am not a professional, any suggestion to enhance the code is very welcome - in particular my edges are a little fuzzy).

The idea was to produce a polygon that looks like a donut, apply a color for each "vertex" interpolated from a color map and a white centercolor placed in the center of the "virtual" donut. (I use doublebuffering to avoid flickering.)

```
List<PointF> drawDonut(float angleA, float angleB, float width, int controlPointCount, float scaling, float centerX, float centerY)
    {
        List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
        if (controlPointCount < 2)
        {
            throw (new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("controlPointCount", "controlPointCount must be >1"));
        }
        if (width <= 0 || width > 100)
        {
            throw (new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("width", "width must be comprised between ]0:100]"));
        }

        List<float> angles = new List<float>();

        for (int i = 0; i < controlPointCount; i++)
        {
            angles.Add(angleA + (angleB - angleA) * (float)i / ((float)controlPointCount - 1.0f));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < angles.Count; i++)
        {
            points.Add(new PointF((float)Math.Cos(angles[i]) * scaling + centerX, (float)Math.Sin(angles[i]) * scaling + centerY));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < angles.Count; i++)
        {
            points.Add(new PointF(((100.0f - width) / 100.0f * (float)Math.Cos(angles[angles.Count - 1 - i])) * scaling + centerX, ((100.0f - width) / 100.0f * (float)Math.Sin(angles[angles.Count - 1 - i])) * scaling + centerY));
        }

        return points;
    }


    private List<Color> pieColor(Color[] MainColors, float[] mainStops, float[] stops)
    {
        List<Color> resultColors = new List<Color>();
        int index = 0;
        float percent;

        if (MainColors.Length != mainStops.Length)
        {
            throw new Exception("number of MainColors and mainStops must be the same");
        }


        if (MainColors.Length < 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < stops.Length; i++)
            {
                resultColors.Add((MainColors.Length == 1) ? MainColors[0] : Color.White);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < stops.Length; i++)
            {
                index = Array.FindIndex(mainStops, x => x > stops[i]);
                if (index == 0)
                {
                    resultColors.Add(MainColors[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (index == -1)
                    {
                        resultColors.Add(MainColors.Last());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        percent = (stops[i] - mainStops[index - 1]) / (mainStops[index] - mainStops[index - 1]) * 100f;
                        resultColors.Add(alphaBlend(MainColors[index - 1], MainColors[index], percent));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return resultColors;
    }

    private Color alphaBlend(Color color1, Color color2, float percent)
    {

        byte R = (byte)(((float)color1.R * (100f - percent) / 100f) + ((float)color2.R * (percent) / 100f));
        byte G = (byte)(((float)color1.G * (100f - percent) / 100f) + ((float)color2.G * (percent) / 100f));
        byte B = (byte)(((float)color1.B * (100f - percent) / 100f) + ((float)color2.B * (percent) / 100f));
        return Color.FromArgb(R, G, B);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        RectangleF rec = e.ClipRectangle;
        float midx = rec.Width / 2;
        float midy = rec.Height / 2;
        float pieSize = (float)Math.Min(midx, midy) * 0.9f;
        float pieWidth = 5f;
        float angleA = -225;
        float angleB = 45;
        int nstops = (int)(Math.Abs(angleA - angleB) / 5 + 1);
        float[] stops;

        stops = new float[nstops];

        for (int i = 0; i < stops.Length; i++)
        {
            stops[i] = i * 100f / (stops.Length - 1);
        }

        List<PointF> myDonut = drawDonut(angleA * (float)Math.PI / 180f, angleB * (float)Math.PI / 180f, pieWidth, nstops, pieSize, midx, midy);

        List<Color> myColors = pieColor(new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Cyan, Color.Blue, Color.Magenta, Color.Red },
                                        new float[] { 0.0f, 100f / 6f, 200f / 6f, 300f / 6f, 400f / 6f, 500f / 6f, 600f / 6f },
                                        stops);

        Color[] myPieColor = new Color[myDonut.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < (myPieColor.Length / 2); i++)
        {
            myPieColor[i] = myColors[i];
            myPieColor[myPieColor.Length - i - 1] = myColors[i];
        }

        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddLines(myDonut.ToArray());
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        using (PathGradientBrush b = new PathGradientBrush(gp))
        {
            b.CenterPoint = new PointF(midx, midy);
            b.CenterColor = Color.White;
            b.SurroundColors = myPieColor;

            e.Graphics.FillPath(b, gp);

        }
    }
}
```